# How can I get the path to the %APPDATA% directory in Python?

Tags: python, appdata

How can I get the path to the `%APPDATA%` directory in Python?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

If you want `AppData\Roaming`

```
import os
print(os.getenv('APPDATA'))
```

If you are looking for `AppData\Local`, then use

```
import os
print(os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA'))
```

For `AppData\Local\Temp` you can get it in this way, which also makes your code portable accross platforms

```
import tempfile
print(tempfile.gettempdir())
```

For the differences:

- Roaming is the folder that would be synchronized with a server if you logged into a domain with a roaming profile (enabling you to log into any computer in a domain and access your favorites, documents, etc. Firefox stores its information here, so you could even have the same bookmarks between computers with a roaming profile.
- Local is the folder that is specific to that computer - any information here would not be synchronized with a server. This folder is equivalent in Windows XP to C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Application Data.

See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/21458/why-are-there-directories-called-local-locallow-and-roaming-under-users-user).

Comment: Note that this returns `AppData\Roaming`. You need `%LOCALAPPDATA%` if you are looking for `AppData\Local`.

Comment: If you are looking for `AppData\LocalLow` you need to use `..\LocalLow` as there is no environment variable as far as I can find.

Answer (score 38):

You may use [os.path.expandvars(path)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars):

> Return the argument with environment variables expanded. Substrings of the form `$name` or `${name}` are replaced by the value of environment variable name. Malformed variable names and references to non-existing variables are left unchanged.
>
> On Windows, `%name%` expansions are supported in addition to `$name` and `${name}`.

This comes handy when combining the expanded value with other path components.

Example:

```python
from os import path

sendto_dir = path.expandvars(r'%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo')
dumps_dir = path.expandvars(r'%LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps')
```

Comment: These days `pathlib` is often more convenient, but, unfortunately it [does not implement expandvars()](https://bugs.python.org/issue21301), although it *does* implement [expanduser()](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.expanduser).

Answer (score 34):

Although the question clearly asks about the Windows-specific `%APPDATA%` directory, perhaps you have ended up here looking for a cross-platform solution for getting the *application data directory for the current user*, which varies by OS.

As of Python 3.11, somewhat surprisingly, there is no built-in function to find this directory. However, there are third-party packages, one of them being [platformdirs](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/), which provides functions to retrieve paths such as:

- user data dir (`user_data_dir`)
- user config dir (`user_config_dir`)
- user cache dir (`user_cache_dir`)
- site data dir (`site_data_dir`)
- site config dir (`site_config_dir`)
- user log dir (`user_log_dir`)

Comment: this answer should have more upvotes

Comment: It says, `platformdirs` should be used instead of `appdirs`, since last is deprecated by authors (reason: `platformdirs` is more maintained fork of `appdir`)

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing:

```
import os
path = os.getenv('APPDATA')
array = os.listdir(path)
print array
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the accepted answer given five years before. OP asked how to get the path, not how to enumerate the contents of a directory.

Answer (score -2):

You can use module called `appdata`. It was developed to get access to different paths for your application, including app data folder. Install it:

```
pip install appdata
```

And after that you can use it this way:

```
from appdata import AppDataPaths
app_paths = AppDataPaths()
app_paths.app_data_path  # for your app data path
app_paths.logs_path  # for logs folder path for your application
```

It allows to to get not only app data folder and logs folder but has other features to manage paths like managing config files paths. And it's customizable.

Links:

1. [Read the Docs](https://appdata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) - documentation.
2. [GitHub](https://github.com/VoIlAlex/appdata) - source code.
3. [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/appdata/) - package manager (pip).

Comment: As the author of `appdata`, you should have a look at [How to not be a spammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion): it says: "if you mention your product [...], you _must_ disclose your affiliation in your post."