# finding the current OS's local data directory

Tags: python, rust, operating-system, cross-platform

i am making an app with python (PyQt6) and rust. i want to add saved data that includes important things, so i want to create a directory in the local data of the current OS (`user/AppData` on windows, `$home/.local` on linux etc). i am aware that i could do this using the `OS` module of both rust and python, but at the same time, this would require me to learn, use and debug every new OS that i want to add into my app, which seems to me like a lot of work. so i was wondering, is there any python/rust module that can find the local data of the current OS? and if not, then can someone show me how would i be able to implement this in python or rust in a way that would require me to learn and debug as little as possible? thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Getting AppData folder in a cross-platform way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078969/python-getting-appdata-folder-in-a-cross-platform-way) Also: [How can I get the path to the %APPDATA% directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184414/how-can-i-get-the-path-to-the-appdata-directory-in-python)