# cx_Freeze created executable has no write permission on boot

Tags: python, permissions, windows-10, cx-freeze, boot

I've created an application (Python 3.6) with cx_Freeze and when ran as a Python command or even the executable works totally fine.

But if I make the application auto-boot on windows 10 (by creating shortcut in shell:startup) the log file it would create or write to raises `PermissionError`. I tried to create a workaround by checking if the file is locked, just add an increment number to the end of the file.

This also works, if I manually make a log file read only, it will create the next one and so on. But with auto boot it raises `RecursionError`, so it has probably absolutely no way to write to the disk.

Is there anyway without giving the application `Run as administrator` to be able to handle the magic of creating a log file when booting up? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to let the application create the log file in the `%APPDATA%` directory or in the `%LOCALAPPDATA%`directory? You can use the following to get the path to these directories in Python:

```
import os
app_data_path = os.getenv('APPDATA')
local_app_data_path = os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA')
print(app_data_path)
print(local_app_data_path)
```

See [How can I get the path to the %APPDATA% directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13184414/8516269)

Comment: Hey I'll get back to you on this, one of the issue would be still that I also have a version file, and that seems to be unreadable too. I might have to workaround on that if the log works in appdata.

Comment: what if we insist to use administrator required folder?