# find path to an application using a python application

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently learning Python and looking to build small apps just for practice. I am wanting to build a Windows application that will delete a folder in the `C:\users\<username>\appdata\roaming` folder. The problem I have is the username will be different depending on what workstation a person is on. I am looking for someone to lead me in the right direction on how I would go about finding this path on each workstation and then deleting a folder within that path. I have looked at relative paths but not sure if I would be able to use that to delete a folder within the `%appdata%` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell me if I got it wrong. Are you stuck trying to get the username dynamically when run from each account? If so, you can try python's `getpass` module as below,

```
import getpass
location = "C:\users\{username}\appdata\roaming".format(username=getpass.getuser())
```

Comment: This is worked great. Now I have to figure out how to to get the function to run until the button is clicked and to delete more than one folder. This is a great site. Thank You for your help!!

Comment: @smitty68521 Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.getlogin() to get the current user and insert it as a placeholder:

```
import os
currentUser=os.getlogin()
folderPath="C:\\{0}\\<username>\\appdata\\roaming".format(currentUser)
os.rmdir(folderPath)       ----> removes an empty directory.
shutil.rmtree(folderPath)  ----> deletes a directory and all its contents.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get the appdata path

```
import os
path = os.getenv('APPDATA')
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184414/how-can-i-get-the-path-to-the-appdata-directory-in-python).

And after, to delete the folder (in this case I deleted the Zoom folder)

```
import shutil
folder_to_delete = os.path.join(path,'Zoom')
shutil.rmtree(folder_to_delete, ignore_errors=True)
```