# what is the correct or best way to input a users home path address into a string?

Tags: python, path

Hello as the title says i am writing a program which copys data from chrome. my current code is

```
#library imports
import sys
import shutil
import os
import subprocess


#search and find requried files.

os.path.expanduser('~user') #search for user path

#Making directory
newpath = r'F:\Evidence\Chromium'
newpath = r'F:\Evidence\Chrome'

#Copy chrome file
original = r'%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History'
target = r'F:\Evidence\Chrome'
shutil.copyfile(original, target)
```

i get a error on the line `original = r'%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History'`

i assume the script cannot read `%LOCALAPPDATA%\` and needs the correct user path ?
what code do i need to input the user directory on a windows PC?

for example `C:\Users\(Script to find out this part)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

```
Scripv3.py", line 25, in <module>
shutil.copyfile(original, target)
File "C:\Users\darks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History'
```

Comment: Please post the traceback message with the full error text.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It makes sense that there would be an error on `shutil.copyfile` as %LOCALAPPDATA% isn't expanded, but the literal string assignment itself doesn't have a problem that I can see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184414/how-can-i-get-the-path-to-the-appdata-directory-in-python; I can't vote to close myself without immediately closing the question, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pathlib` library.

```
from pathlib import Path

original = Path.home() / "Google/Chrome/User data/Default/History"
target = Path("F:/Evidence/Chrome")

shutil.copyfile(origina, target)
```

Comment: May delete; this doesn't address the use of `%LOCALAPPDATA%` to specify a specific directory.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use `os.path.expandvars()` function on `original` variable:

```
os.path.expandvars(r'%LOCALAPPDATA%')
```

Will return:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local
```

Where `USERNAME` is the name of the current user.

So, ensure the variables are expanded for this path:

```
original = os.path.expandvars(original)
```

before using it in `shutil.copy(original, target)`

Comment: thank you for the solutions so far i will try them tomorrow and see if there is any progress.