# Pyinstaller app: AccessDenied on folder creation running on system startup

Tags: python, pyinstaller, nsis, access-denied, autostart

I have a simple script:

```
def get_log_dir():
    time_stmp = datetime.now().strftime('%m%d-%H%M%S')
    dir_ = Path('..') / f'log_{time_stmp}'
    dir_.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    return dir_


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = get_log_dir()
```

I build it to exe with `pyinstaller --debug all -n minimal minimal.py`.
Then I create a simple installer with NSIS:

```
  Name "myAppName"
  OutFile ".\myApp.exe"

  SilentInstall silent

  InstallDir "$LOCALAPPDATA\MyApp-0.1.1"
  
  RequestExecutionLevel admin

Section "Main Section" SecMain

  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  
  File /r ".\myApp-app\*"

  WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" "myApp" '"$InstDir\minimal.exe"'

  ;Store installation folder
  WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\myApp" "" $INSTDIR
  
  Exec '"$INSTDIR\minimal.exe"'

SectionEnd
```

After running the installer i get my exe put to AppData folder and there is a registry entry in HKLM. It correctly starts at the end of installation, I can also start it manually at any time.
However, if I restart my machine the script starts as it is supposed to but it fails with Access Denied error while trying to create folder. What could be causing this and/or how to debug this? Are there any Windows logs that could be investigated? Maybe pyInstaller logs?

Update:
Interestingly it works if instead of modifying registry I create a shortcut and put it to `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. The question now is how does it differ and why? Is the walk around a clean solution or should be considered a hack?

Comment: Does minimal.exe request UAC elevation?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: When you are installing for just the current user you should use `RequestExecutionLevel user` and only HKCU, not HKLM.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a Run entry and a shortcut is that a shortcut can provide additional properties like setting the current directory.

This leads me to believe that `Path('..')` in your Python script is the problem because the current directory is unspecified for a Run entry and in real life is probably the Windows directory where you don't have write access.

The solution is to replace `..` with [the full path of the .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/404744/3501). Trying to find the path of the current script is [surprisingly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3718657/3501) [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/q/595305/3501). The [appdirs package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66169954/3501) can also help you find an appropriate directory for log files...